# How to use two different price templates / list and detail view

Tags: template

within the following file I can see below shown code:

File:

```
frontend/default/ves_fashion/template/common/list/default.phtml
```

Code:

```
<div class="price">
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, $price_prefix) ?>
</div>
```

If I navigate to

```
frontend/default/ves_fashion/template/catalog/product/price.phtml
```

and make some changes to the price.phtml file, I can see the changes on two parts:

1. The price which is shown for each product in the product overview
   section.
2. The price which is shown for one product in the detail view.

**How can I change the template that two different price templates are loaded - one for the overview section, and a different one for the detailed section?**

I tried to rename

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, $price_prefix) ?>
```

to

```
<?php echo $this->getPricelistHtml($_product, true, $price_prefix) ?>
```

And clone price.phtml as pricelist.phtml, but this is not working correctly.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: please try this <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, $price_prefix) ->setTemplate('common/list/default.phtml');?>

Comment: This results in:
 Call to a member function setTemplate() on a non-object

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addPriceBlockType`, so for example:

```
<reference name="product_list">
   <action method="addPriceBlockType">
      <type>simple</type>
      <block>catalog/product_price</block>
      <template>catalog/product/list/custom-price.phtml</template>
   </action>
</reference>
```

Comment: Hey Mayers, and where do i put this xml code reference?

Comment: In your layout xml : `<catalog_category_layered> ...code here.. </catalog_category_layered>` and `<catalog_category_default> .. code here... </catalog_category_default>`

Comment: I added it to both blocks directly before ```</catalog_category_default>``` and ```</catalog_category_layered>```. I still use ```$this->getPriceHtml``` but the shop still takes ```template/catalog/product/price.phtml``` and not ```custom-price.html``` ... What is missing? Do you have an idea?

Comment: Hi Torben, it's hard to say without looking at the code. If you're not familiar with Magento, I would advise giving this to a Magento developer, as understanding layouts takes some practise.